# transforming to linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is it possible to transform following code to Linq that it will look like little bit more nicely

```
foreach (var entry in bottleneck.Item2)
{
    if(entry.ChangeoverTime > 0)
    {
        avarangechangeOverTimes += entry.ChangeoverTime;
        ++counter;
    }

    if (entry.ChangeoverTime > maxchangeOverTimes)
    {
        maxchangeOverTimes = entry.ChangeoverTime;
    }

    changeovertime.ChangeoverTimes.Add
    (
        new ChangeOverDateValue
        {
            ChangeoverValue = entry.ChangeoverTime,
            Color = ChangeOverTimeToColor(entry.ChangeoverTime),
            StartTime = entry.StartTime
        }
     );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of entries in `bottleneck.Item2` isn't huge, you could achieve the same using these three statements:

```
var maxChangeOverTime = bottleneck.Item2.Max(x => x.ChangeoverTime);
var averageChangeOverTime = bottleneck.Item2.Average(x => x.ChangeoverTime);
var result
    = bottleneck.Item2
                .Select(x => new ChangeOverDateValue
                             {
                                 ChangeoverValue = x.ChangeoverTime,
                                 Color = ChangeOverTimeToColor(x.ChangeoverTime),
                                 StartTime = x.StartTime
                             });
changeovertime.ChangeoverTimes.AddRange(result);
```

Please note that this will enumerate `bottleneck.Item2` three times instead of one time with your current code.

Comment: Depends on what bottleneck is. It will always iterate but if bottleneck is a dbcontext then the linq statement will be translated to sql. Other then that +1 for best solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can only change the external foreach:

```
bottleneck.Items2.ToList().Foreach(entry =>
{
// your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bottleneck.Item2.where(entry => entry.ChangeoverTime).ToList().Foreach(entry => {
    avarangechangeOverTimes += entry.ChangeoverTime;
    ++counter;
});


maxchangeOverTimes = bottleneck.Item2.max=(entry => entry.ChangeoverTime);

changeovertime.ChangeoverTimes.AddAll(bottleneck.Item2.select(entry => new new ChangeOverDateValue
                    {
                        ChangeoverValue = entry.ChangeoverTime,
                        Color = ChangeOverTimeToColor(entry.ChangeoverTime),
                        StartTime = entry.StartTime
                    }));
```

this is all i can come up with without having more info or my development envirment with me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
var avarangechangeOverTimes = bottleneck.Item2
                                    .Where(entry => entry.ChangeOverTime > 0)
                                    .Sum(entry => entry.ChangeOverTime);

var maxchangeOverTimes = bottleneck.Item2
                                    .Max(entry => entry.ChangeOverTime);

bottleneck.Item2.ToList()
        .ForEach(entry => changeovertime.ChangeoverTimes.Add
                                    (
                                        new ChangeOverDateValue {
                                            ChangeoverValue = entry.ChangeoverTime,
                                            Color = ChangeOverTimeToColor(entry.ChangeoverTime),
                                            StartTime = entry.StartTime
                                        }

                                   )
                                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var averagechangeOverTimes = bottleneck.Item2
                                       .Where(entry => entry.ChangeoverTime > 0)
                                       .Sum(entry => entry.ChangeoverTime);

counter = bottleneck.Item2.Count(entry => entry.ChangeoverTime > 0);

var maxchangeOverTimes = bottleneck.Item2.Max(entry => entry.ChangeoverTimes);

changeovertime.ChangeoverTime.Add(bottleneck.Item2
                                            .Select(entry => new ChangeOverDateValue{
                                                        ChangeoverValue = entry.ChangeoverTime,
                                                        Color = ChangeOverTimeToColor(entry.ChangeoverTime),
                                                        StartTime = entry.StartTime
                                                      });
```